How one can create a just task's arguments autocompletion?
I have found no answer to the question in title in documentation nor GitHub issues nor PRs.
Is it possible to do something like that at all and if yes, could you please point me to documentation, source code or anything which can explain how to archive task arguments completion?
Below is a long explanation with example of what I would like to be able to do.
Let's say I created a task in my justfile with name task-a which accepts one argument with values x, y, z.
At the moment even if I setup auto completions for just (i.e. with source <(~/.cargo/bin/just --completions bash) command in ~/.bashrc) I wasn't able to type just task-a press and get auto completion suggestions for x, y, z. Or when I type just task-a w where w if first letter of x value and then press I would like to get completion to the full value of x.
Another example of this could be when I have task-b which accepts one argument which is a list (or filtered list) of files in a specific project directory. Then typing just task-b some-fi and then I would get a completion to just task-b some-file-name where some-file-name is a name of the file existing somewhere and implementation of task-b define where to find that file. In this case I don't assume just be smart enough to understand implementation of task-b I just want to explain (i.e. provide a path or mask to files) which can be used as potential variants for auto completion.
